# How to multiply values in XPATH?

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I have a bunch of

```
<item price='n' sold='m'>
...
</item>
```

I want to do price * sold on each of the items. I am trying

```
'//item/(@price * @sold)'
```

from inside lxml in python, but I keep getting the error *'Invalid Expression'*. The same happens with xmllint command too. 
But the same query works in Oxygen xml editor.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Calculations can be done in XPath 2.0 as I have been corrected!

If you want to select everything where the price is lower or equal than sold price times 2 it is possible. See next:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Number_functions

Comment: Downvoting, the answer misses the point which is that this syntax is valid in XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 5):

The XPath expression you're using requires XPath 2.0. (You can verify this in Oxygen by setting the XPath version to 1.0 and trying your query again.) I don't think lxml supports XPath 2.0.

If you can't get a library that supports XPath 2.0, then instead of trying to do it all inside XPath, you'll need to:

- select the `<item>` elements in XPath, e.g. using the XPath expression `//item`
- loop through these elements in Python
- in the context of each `<item>` element, evaluate the XPath expression `@price * @sold`

Comment: thanks for your prompt answer, much appreciated. I have chosen the other Answer as correct only on the basis of timing. Thanks again.

Comment: @Karthick: you're welcome. Regarding acceptance (check mark) - I don't mind that you chose the other answer. But in general, I would say, don't feel like you need to "accept" the first answer. The site will be more valuable as we encourage helpful and accurate answers, not just quick ones.