# Sum of node value and attribute multiplied by using XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

Say you have an XML that looks like this:

```
<scores>
    <score cnt="2">10</score>
    <score cnt="0">20</score>
    <score cnt="1">50</score>
</scores>
```

What I would like to get is the total sum which should be 70 = (2*10 + 1*50). So, multiplication between the node value and it's attribute and the final sum of all the nodes.

Sure enough I know how to make a sum of just values: `sum(//score)`, or attributes `sum(//score/@cnt)` but I can't figure out how to put these two together. How could this be done?

Comment: not possible in xpath 1.0? [How to multiply values in XPATH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959129/how-to-multiply-values-in-xpath)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a calculation is not possible with a single XPath 1.0 expression. If you can use XPath 2.0, it can be done:

```
sum(for $x in /scores/score return $x * $x/@cnt)
```

**EDIT** An even shorter equivalent path expression, albeit more cryptic, would be

```
sum(/scores/score/(. * @cnt))
```

Thanks to Ian Roberts for suggesting it.

An XSLT stylesheet to [prove it](http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKws):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <result>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(for $x in /scores/score return $x * $x/@cnt)"/>
      </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

and the result will be

```
<result>70</result>
```

Comment: `sum(/scores/score/(. * @cnt))` should also work but in my opinion the explicit `for` is clearer.